# Uninstalled Ubuntu, now error:no such partition

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, partition-recovery

I uninstalled Ubuntu yesterday. I deleted the partition and extended my Windows partition using the tool.

I now get a black DOS screen and the error :

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
```

when I run ls, it returns

```
(hd0)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have deleted the Ubuntu's partition but the GRUB2 is still in your MBR.
As you have installed Ubuntu, it has replaced your windows bootloader.

Try to restore your Windows bootloader: [How to restore the Windows bootloader](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708)

Take a look (starting with `fixboot`, `fixmbr` and so on).
Good luck!